# passing an array from controller angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I've got a function here where I want to choose a random name from inside the array to display.

In my controller, I have set up an array called `names`. I then want to pass it into my `$scope.message` function and have it called from the my html.

I keep getting an error:

```
"Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
        {{message(names)}}
        {{}}
```

my controller:

```
eventsApp.controller("EventController", function EventController($scope)
{

    var names = ["David", "Tony", "Tim", "David", "Daniel", "Tom"];

    var randomChoose = function(array){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length-1);

    };
    $scope.message = function(array){
        var name = array.indexOf(randomChoose(array));
        return "Hello"+name;
    };
});
```

My html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
        {{message(names)}}
        {{}}
    </div>

</div>
```

Thank you. I tried to changing `names` to `$scope.names` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I think you will definitely need to have names in the scope for this to work

Comment: What is the point of the empty curly brackets (`{{}}`) in the markup? That seems to be what the problem is.

Comment: works fine here with adjustments... including $scope.names...and proper array lookup   http://plnkr.co/edit/kfajKG3QtsMzDIOahMQW?p=preview . If you were using your console to check values in controller (basic debugging) would have figured more out

Comment: Tried `$scope.names = [..]` or `{{message()}}` ?  BTW, `array.indexOf` should be  `array[..]`

Comment: Thanks, when I run it i like 5 times it says `"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` . I'm not updating anything except changing the name every time page is reloaded.

Comment: not a good idea having a random generator function passed to view if you don't understand how angular digests work. Can cause too many digests because each one changes the value, each scope change causes another digest cycle...can be infinite loop. Assign a value to scope variable from generator and only pass variable to view

Comment: put `console.log()` in that random generator...will see it called many times just loading page. Best practice is avoid functions in markup for display purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your randomness logic seems wrong, a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pqyguet1/3/):

```
function EventController($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["David", "Tony", "Tim", "David", "Daniel", "Tom"];

    var randomChoose = function(array){
        return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    };

    $scope.message = function(array){
        var name = randomChoose(array);
        return "Hello " + name;
    };

}
```